# How do I type hint for Enums in Python?

Tags: python, enums, type-hinting

I have a python function for which I want to use type hinting.
There are two arguments. The first is any Enum class, the second optional arg is an element of that Enum.

For example, say I have:

```
class Foo(Enum):
    ALPHA = 1
    BETA = 2
    GAMMA = 3
```

The first arg would be, e.g. Foo, the second would be e.g. Foo.ALPHA

What would be the correct way of type hinting this? What I have so far is:

```
def switch(options: Enum, selected: Optional[Enum] = None) -> Enum:
   # Rest of fn...
```

but that doesn't seem right.

Comment: Possibly a dumb question, but why not use just one argument that is either an Enum or an Enum member?

Comment: The logic in the function uses both the Enum and the Enum member. Depending on which Enum member is selected (or None) the return value will be different.

Comment: I was thinking something along the lines of: `def switch(options): selected=None; if isinstance(options, Enum): options, selected = options.__class__, options`.  I just don't like typing the same thing over and over.  :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define a `TypeVar` with `Enum` as a bound, and then specify that your function takes the `Type` of that typevar and returns an instance of it:

```
from enum import Enum
from typing import Optional, Type, TypeVar

_E = TypeVar('_E', bound=Enum)

def switch(
    options: Type[_E],
    selected: Optional[_E] = None
) -> _E:
    ...
```

Testing it in `mypy` with an actual `Enum` subclass:

```
class Foo(Enum):
    ALPHA = 1
    BETA = 2
    GAMMA = 3

reveal_type(switch(Foo, Foo.ALPHA))  # Revealed type is "Foo"
```

Comment: Fab. Thanks. I didn't know about this, but looks like it does the trick.